# Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native

```js
const Pedir = async () => {
  const subscriptioncp = DataStore.observe(CartProduct).subscribe();
  const userID = (await getCurrentUser()).userId;
  const shopID = cartProducts[0].product!.shopID;
  const shop = await DataStore.query(Shop, (s) => s.id.eq(shopID));
  let phone: string = shop[0].phoneNumber;

  interface product {
    quantity: string;
    title: string | undefined;
    option: string | undefined | null;
  }

  let productos: product[] = [];

  cartProducts.map((cp) => {
    let i = 0;
    let quantity: string = cp.quantity.toString();
    productos[i] = {
      quantity: quantity,
      title: cp.product?.title,
      option: cp.option,
    };
    console.log(productos[i]); // 'productos' logs every item correctly here
    i++;
    return;
  });

  if (totalPrice === 0 || !shopID) {
    Alert.alert("Aviso:", "Tu carrito está vacío", [
      {
        text: "Ok",
        onPress: () => console.log("Ok Pressed"),
        style: "default",
      },
    ]);
    return subscriptioncp.unsubscribe();
  } else {
    subscriptioncp.unsubscribe();
    return await Linking.openURL(
      "https://wa.me/".concat(phone) +
        "?text=Hola, deseo hacer un pedido de los siguientes productos:\n" +
        productos[0].quantity +
        " " +
        productos[0].title +
        " " +
        productos[0].option +
        "\n" +
        productos[1].quantity + // the warning shows here, cant read this property
        " " +
        productos[1].title +
        " " +
        productos[1].option
    );
  }
};
```

I want to send the data of every item in the array `productos` to the `OpenURL` as a WhatsApp message, it worked at first when I tried sending just the first item (`productos[0]`), but once I added the second item the error popped up, I thought the source of this problem was that the data from the second item was not set yet when trying to send it on the `OpenURL`, yet it logs correctly in the `cartProducts.map()` function, don't know why it doesn't work, I'm new to TypeScript and I struggle a lot with it, any help will be very appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some odd things here like maintaining index counters inside of a `map`.

Ultimately, the problem is because `let i = 0;` is *inside* the `map` callback meaning you will only ever set the first item of the `productos` array, since every time the `map` callback runs, `i` is set back to `0`, so the `i++` is nullified.

Your log shows every item because you are logging out each iteration of the `map` callback, but that is not the same as `productus` being populated. If you logged out `productos` underneath the whole `map` call, you'd see it contains only ever one item, and that item would also be the *last* item in `cartProducts` (since for every iteration of `map`, it will just overwrite index `0` with the current one).

You could move the `let i = 0` line above the entire `map` call itself, but frankly, it'd be better to refactor a little (you should read up on how `map` is used).

In addition, I believe the intermediary `productos` structure doesn't even need to exist. We can simply map to the final desired string directly from `cartProducts`. This will reduce complexity and increase readability.

Here it is cleaned up:

```
const Pedir = async () => {
  const subscriptioncp = DataStore.observe(CartProduct).subscribe();
  const userID = (await getCurrentUser()).userId;
  const shopID = cartProducts[0].product!.shopID;
  const shop = await DataStore.query(Shop, (s) => s.id.eq(shopID));
  let phone: string = shop[0].phoneNumber;

  interface product {
    quantity: string;
    title: string | undefined;
    option: string | undefined | null;
  }

  if (totalPrice === 0 || !shopID) {
    Alert.alert("Aviso:", "Tu carrito está vacío", [
      {
        text: "Ok",
        onPress: () => console.log("Ok Pressed"),
        style: "default",
      },
    ]);
    return subscriptioncp.unsubscribe();
  } else {
    subscriptioncp.unsubscribe();
    return await Linking.openURL(
      "https://wa.me/".concat(phone) +
        "?text=Hola, deseo hacer un pedido de los siguientes productos:\n" +
        cartProducts
          .map(
            (cp) =>
              `${cp.quantity.toString()} ${cp.product?.title} ${cp.option}`,
          )
          .join("\n"),
    );
  }
};
```

What is happening here is that for every item in cart products, we return the single string that represents it. That will result in an array of those strings (one for each cart product). We then turn this array of strings into one long string by joining them with the new line `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining everything so clearly and giving the extra advice, now i get what i was doing wrong, i obviously still have a lot to learn but you were really helpful, saved my life with this one...

Comment: No worries! Would you mind marking as accepted if you're happy with it? Thanks